# Imagem dos avatares e do corpo das Q&A não estão aparecendo para mim

Tags: bug, suporte, status-nãorepro

O que pode estar causando, ou qual o motivo das imagens de avatar não estarem aparecendo para mim?

[image: print]

Nem mesmo essa que inseri no conteúdo da pergunta.

Comment: Sua conexão usa proxy?

Comment: Olá @perdeu! Não, minha conexão não usa proxy.

Comment: Isso acontece comigo às vezes também

Comment: O problema acontece comigo também e está cada vez pior.

Comment: Se eu lembrar depois faço um teste com tipos de imagens diferentes (jpg, png ..) porque de alguns aparecem, de outros e inclusive o meu não aparece. Até mesmo a imagem que coloquei como exemplo no corpo da mensagem não aparece.

Comment: Mas elas nunca aparecem, ou é um problema intermitente?

Comment: @bfavaretto, a minha e as imagens no corpo das questões, não aparecem nesse computador que é o da minha empresa. Em minha rede doméstica com meu notebook aparece. Em meu celular, tanto na rede de minha casa quanto na rede de minha empresa aparecem. Nesse momento, no computador de minha empresa, aparece a do bigown mas a minha e a imagem que adicionei ao corpo da questão não aparecem. A sua apareceu ao visualizar seu perfil. Então, respondendo sua pergunta, aqui, depois de um tempo, nunca mais apareceram algumas.

Comment: Já tentou limpar o cache do navegador?

Comment: @bfavaretto, limpo direto. E uso o Chrome. No IE funcionou, vou instalar o Firefox.

Comment: @bfavaretto, Instalei o Firefox. Nova instalação, cache limpo (claro) e não aparece.

Comment: Em outros sites da rede SE também.

Comment: Será que a rede da sua empresa não está barrando o acesso ao [imgur](http://imgur.com/)? Pela sua descrição, talvez só as imagens hospedadas lá não estejam sendo exibidas, de modo que apenas as fotos de perfil vindas do [Gravatar](https://pt.gravatar.com/) apareçam ok (a do @bigown parece ser do Gravatar).

Comment: Posso garantir que não há bloqueio no meu acesso. Aparentemente só não consigo ver os avatares de usuários novos de uma data pra cá. Não vejo nas listagens, nos posts, no perfil do usuário. Mas os que eu já via, continuo vendo sempre.